# Parse DateTime Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

I have a variable which is datetime type. How can i get the shortdatetostring() as datetime variable type ? I have a column in databae as datetime type. I would like to get the records which are added at a certain day.

Example:

```
 SELECT id FROM database WHERE added like @p1
```

The parameter of the query is a datetime variable.

Comment: `like` is for string comparisons, using the `%` wildcard and not for datetime columns

Comment: yeah .. i read about it a few seconds ago..

Comment: You might be able to simplify this by editing the query, actually. Try `select id from database where cast(added as date) = cast(@p1 as date)` This (effectively) strips the time from `added` as well as the time from `@p1` and compares the dates only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match based on day, month, and year of the date variables.  Do not use strings, since matching is slow.

```
SELECT id 
    FROM database 
    WHERE Datepart(yy, added) = Datepart(yy, @p1)
      AND  Datepart(mm, added) = Datepart(mm, @p1)
      AND Datepart(dd, added) = Datepart(dd, @p1)
```

Comment: and how do i get just the yy,mm,dd from datetime variable ?

Comment: just pass in the date time directly into the parameter, so @p1 is a datetime

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in order to get all the ids on the 26th of January.

```
SELECT id FROM database WHERE added >= '2012-01-26' and added < '2012-01-27'
```

Comment: That should be `>=`, otherwise you'll miss any values that indicate midnight.

Comment: my question : how can i get this '2012-01-26' in c# language. I mean dynamiclly

Answer (score 0):

In C# you do like below.

```
DateTime dt;
string Temp1 = "Your Date";
if (DateTime.TryParse(Temp1, out dt))
{
     // If it is a valid date
     string date = dt.ToShortDateString();
     string time = dt.ToShortTimeString();
}
```

In SQL Server

```
SELECT id FROM database WHERE Datepart(dd, added) = Datepart(dd, @p1)
```

Please see below the sample

```
create table #temp
(
    dat datetime,
)

insert into #temp(dat)values(GETDATE())
insert into #temp(dat)values(GETDATE()+1)
insert into #temp(dat)values(GETDATE()+2)

select * from #temp where DATEPART(dd, dat) > 27
drop table #temp
```

[image]

Comment: it's not working .. added column is datetime. @parametername should be datetime too..

Comment: please check my edit for sample usuage of datepart in sql query

Comment: dd = day ?   still not what i want .. dd should be another parameter ?

Comment: Yes it is day. as you mentioned in ur query "I would like to get the records which are added at a certain day."

Comment: Let me know where you are facing the issue...?

Comment: the day(date) should be introduced by the user... by the way .. thank you for the help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7080/discussion-between-stackoverflow-user-and-emil-dumbazu)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parameterised queries the format of the datetime type doesn't matter.
Got to remember that "2012-01-26" is a string not a date....

If you need a Date formatted a particular way, then myDateTime.ToString(....), there are several overloads, one of which is simply a format String e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd"

If you want to parse a string into a datetime then DateTime.Parse(...), again there are several overloads.

More on dates after comment

DateTime.Parse("12/31/2012") gives you a datetime type in c#. 
It parses the string into a DateTime

MyDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") gives you a string of  date in the specified format.

"31/12/2012" is not a date, if you want it as a date, then you Parse it into one.

Now which way do you want to go DateTime to a string, or string to a DateTime, or are you asking something completely different?

If you want to only Parse DateTimes trhat are in the format mm/dd/yyyy, you can't because when it's string there's absolutely no way to tell the 6th of August from the 8th of June, unless you assume the format is always mm/dd/yyyy which is pretty much guaranteed to go badly wrong at somepoint, which is why when going from Date to String YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD are the way to go.

If it's what you want / have to do then

```
DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.Parse("12/31/2012",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Pass a string in a format that doesn't fit the pattern and it will throw an exception, NB that would include "31/12/2012".

CultureInfo is in the System.Globalisation namespace.

There area number of options. Current, CurrentUI, Invariant etc. Which one you use depends on how you are setup and globalisation / internationalisation requirements (even if they are none). So using Current Culture, would assume US default regional settings. But if I was to run your code, then "31/12/2012" would work and "12/31/2012" would blow chunks.

If you want to fix the formats no matter what system they are run on then InvariantCulture is the way to go. Don't forget to set the neutral language as well. Hit the assembly button on the Applications tab of the project's property pages. Neutral language is a drop down near the bottom. Presumably you want en-us.

If you don't want the excpetion then it's

```
DateTime myDateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParse("12/31/2012",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out myDateTime)
{
   // do something with myDateTime...
}
else
{
    // do something about the value not being in the correct format
}
```

Comment: From DateTime.Parse i would like to get only mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to simplify this by editing the query, actually. Try

```
select id from database where cast(added as date) = cast(@p1 as date)
```

This (effectively) strips the time from `added` as well as the time from `@p1` and compares the dates only.